# How can I get employess who earn less money than their managers? - ORACLE - SCOTT database

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to receive name of employess who earn less than their managers. There are three departments and all of them have got manager. Subquery in brackets returns salary of this managers correct. I also tried to receive all workers without managers but my code is always wrong. Do you know what I should correct?

```
SELECT sal
FROM SCOTT.emp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT sal
                  FROM SCOTT.emp
                  WHERE job LIKE 'MANAGER');
```

This is my table:

| EMPNO | ENAME | JOB | MGR | HIREDATE | SAL | COMM | DEPTNO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7369 | SMITH | CLERK | 7902 | 80/12/17 | 800 |  | 20 |
| 7499 | ALLEN | SALESMAN | 7698 | 81/02/20 | 1600 | 300 | 30 |
| 7521 | WARD | SALESMAN | 7698 | 81/02/22 | 1250 | 500 | 30 |
| 7566 | JONES | MANAGER | 7839 | 81/04/02 | 2975 |  | 20 |
| 7654 | MARTIN | SALESMAN | 7698 | 81/09/28 | 1250 | 1400 | 30 |
| 7698 | BLAKE | MANAGER | 7839 | 81/05/01 | 2850 |  | 30 |
| 7782 | CLARK | MANAGER | 7839 | 81/06/09 | 2450 |  | 10 |
| 7839 | KING | PRESIDENT |  | 81/11/17 | 5000 |  | 10 |
| 7844 | TURNER | SALESMAN | 7698 | 81/09/08 | 1500 | 0 | 30 |
| 7900 | JAMES | CLERK | 7698 | 81/12/03 | 950 |  | 30 |
| 7902 | FORD | ANALYST | 7566 | 81/12/03 | 3000 |  | 20 |
| 7934 | MILLER | CLERK | 7782 | 82/01/23 | 1300 |  | 10 |

Comment: That's Scott's schema, @Austin; sample data is *well known* for at least 35-40 years.

Comment: I' ve got them, but I'm new to Oracle and I know what I must receive but NOT EXISTS always returns me empty table

Comment: According to https://www.businessinsider.com/whatever-happened-to-oracles-founders-in-this-iconic-photo-2012-8#bruce-scott-the-first-employee-2, yes, he is, @Austin :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a hierarchical query:

```sql
SELECT ename,
       PRIOR ename AS mgr_ename,
       sal,
       PRIOR sal AS mgr_sal
FROM   emp
WHERE  (LEVEL = 2 AND sal < PRIOR sal) -- salary is less than manager's salary
OR     (LEVEL = 1 AND mgr IS NULL) -- has no manager
CONNECT BY PRIOR empno = mgr
```

Which outputs:

> | ENAME | MGR_ENAME | SAL | MGR_SAL |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | ADAMS | SCOTT | 1100 | 3000 |
> | SMITH | FORD | 800 | 3000 |
> | MILLER | CLARK | 1300 | 2450 |
> | ALLEN | BLAKE | 1600 | 2850 |
> | JAMES | BLAKE | 950 | 2850 |
> | TURNER | BLAKE | 1500 | 2850 |
> | MARTIN | BLAKE | 1250 | 2850 |
> | WARD | BLAKE | 1250 | 2850 |
> | KING |  | 5000 |  |
> | JONES | KING | 2975 | 5000 |
> | CLARK | KING | 2450 | 5000 |
> | BLAKE | KING | 2850 | 5000 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1d40c8cc44b5e4314310812a15eabe27)*

Answer (score 2):

Looks like self join to me.

```
SQL> select e.ename employee, e.sal sal_employee,
  2         m.ename manager , m.sal sal_manager
  3  from emp e join emp m on e.mgr = m.empno
  4  where e.sal < m.sal;

EMPLOYEE   SAL_EMPLOYEE MANAGER    SAL_MANAGER
---------- ------------ ---------- -----------
JAMES               950 BLAKE             2850
TURNER             1500 BLAKE             2850
MARTIN             1250 BLAKE             2850
WARD               1250 BLAKE             2850
ALLEN              1600 BLAKE             2850
MILLER             1300 CLARK             2450
ADAMS              1100 SCOTT             3000
CLARK              2450 KING              5000
BLAKE              2850 KING              5000
JONES              2975 KING              5000
SMITH               800 FORD              3000

11 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: Is there any option to do this using only employee table?

Comment: This *is* only the EMP table.